# Query slow in new registration

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that I do queries normally, but after I inserted a certain year the query for that year is slow and sometimes it does not return in less than 1 second this command returns

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM mov_table
  WHERE type = 'A' AND year = '2020'
```

This command was running for 5 minutes and did not return

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM mov_table
  WHERE type = 'A' AND year = '2021'
```

This year 2021 was the last insert I made

I need this command to return fast.

Comment: For performance related questions we require your table definitions, index definitions, and execution plan (using Paste The Plan).

Comment: Please provide the table schema and indexes. You are after a random 1000 rows?